# PL/SQL While/For Loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm a DBA, just trying to write a piece of code to capture user privileges in Oracle and write to a table. The below code works ok for one user, but if the ELSE part has multiple users I get the error: "ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows". Makes sense, I realise I need a for/while loop to handle multiple rows, can someone help me with that?

'''

```
declare
   altersystem       varchar2(550);
   altersystemconcat varchar2(550);
begin
   select grantee
     into altersystem
     from dba_sys_privs
    where privilege = 'ALTER SYSTEM'
      and grantee not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM');
   if altersystem = 'No rows selected'
   then
      insert into catch
      values
         ('900'
         ,'No custom users with the Alter System privilege.');
   else
      select concat('The following user/role has the Alter System privilege, revoke if not required: '
                   ,altersystem)
        into altersystemconcat
        from dual;
      insert into catch
      values
         ('100'
         ,altersystemconcat);
   end if;
end;
/
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `select ... INTO ...` requires **exactly one row** to be returned, otherwise you get an exception. Usually you have to loop over a cursor, but you can do it even in a single command like this:

```
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO catch
    SELECT 900, 'The following user/role has the Alter System privilege, revoke if not required: '||grantee 
    FROM dba_sys_privs 
    WHERE PRIVILEGE = 'ALTER SYSTEM' 
        AND grantee NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM');

   IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
      INSERT INTO catch VALUES (100, 'No custom users with the Alter System privilege.');       
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: This is perfect, much easier than my fudged attempt! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Umm ... no, `ELSE`'s `SELECT` doesn't return `too-many-rows`. It selects from `DUAL` which has only 1 row so ...

I suspect it is the first statement, `select grantee into altersystem`. If there's more than one user that satisfies those conditions, you can't put them all into the variable which is declared as `varchar2`. Therefore, yes - a loop might help, it is simple enough.

But, why? Why don't you simply insert all those *offenders* using single `insert`? Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO catch
   SELECT '000', grantee
     FROM dba_sys_privs
    WHERE     privilege = 'ALTER SYSTEM'
          AND grantee NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM');
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single SQL statement - no need for PL/SQL (unless you need it as a stored procedure):

```
INSERT INTO catch (col1, col2) -- change col1 and col2 to the correct column_names in catch that you're inserting into
  WITH no_users AS (SELECT 100 no_user_present_id, 'No custom users with the Alter System privilege.' no_user_text FROM dual),
    users_there AS (SELECT 900 user_present_id, 'The following user/role has the Alter System privilege, revoke if not required: '||grantee user_there_text
                    FROM   dba_sys_privs
                    WHERE  PRIVILEGE = 'ALTER SYSTEM'
                    AND    grantee NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM'))
  SELECT COALESCE(ut.user_present_id, nu.no_user_present_id) ID,
         COALESCE(ut.user_there_text, nu.no_user_text) text
  FROM   no_users nu
         LEFT OUTER JOIN users_there ut ON 1 = 1;
```

This works by using an outer join so that the row for when there's no user is always returned. If there are no users present, the row that is returned is the default row. If there are users that have the specified grant, you will get the rows for those users returned.

Answer (score -2):

Using the listagg function you can concatenate the resulting string.

Commented out the insert statements as I don't have the catch table. Printing to output instead.

Use an exception handler in case no rows found.

```
declare
   altersystem       varchar2(550);
   altersystemconcat varchar2(550);
begin

   select listagg(grantee, ', ') within group(order by grantee) "Grantee"
     into altersystem
     from dba_sys_privs
    where privilege = 'ALTER SYSTEM'
      and grantee not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM');

  dbms_output.put_line('The following user/role has the Alter System privilege, revoke if not required: ' || altersystem);
  /*
 insert into catch
   values
      ('100'
      ,'The following user/role has the Alter System privilege, revoke if not required: ' || altersystem);
  */

exception
   when no_data_found then

dbms_output.put_line('No custom users with the Alter System privilege.');

/*
      insert into catch
      values
         ('900'
         ,'No custom users with the Alter System privilege.');
*/
end;
/
```